# Error magento 2 sales shipment

Tags: magento2

An error occurred during Logging Action execution. Error is Call to a member function getText() on string [] []

Comment: Share full error trace string.

Comment: The error appears on the system log when I try to create a shipment from the order.
[2023-01-05 15:00:52] main.ERROR: An error occurred during Logging Action execution. Error is Call to a member function getText() on string [] []

Comment: Hello, any update on this ?